# Spring Data JPA: save list of parents where children have been moved between parents in one transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of parents where each one-to-many parent has a list of many-to-one children. Orphan removal is on and the relationship is lazy.

I use a `JpaRepository` with Hibernate.

I need to move children between parents and save all changes in a single transaction.

It works fine if I load the list of parents, move children between them (by updating both sides of the relationship) and save the persons in the list one by one in a loop, so that each person gets saved in its own transaction.

But when I put the loop into a method which is annotated with `@Transactional`, so as to hold the entire saving procedure in one overarching transaction which rolls back, should one of the save calls fail, the children will *sometimes* not be stored correctly.

When I save one by one in separate transactions, Hibernate simply *updates* the child row if it has been moved from another parent to the parent which is currently being saved, but *deletes and reinserts* the child if it has been removed from the parent which is currently being saved. I can see that in the SQL logs.

When I save in a single transaction, this seems to fail: some children are not moved properly, rather they are lost.

I also tried to use `saveAll()` instead of looping in an `@Transactional` method, same effect.

Is moving children between parents and saving all parents in a single transaction not a supported scenario?

Comment: `this seems to fail` what is the error? I think the issue is that when you swap children between parents, some conflict occurs in the big transaction. I am not 100% sure that you have a single transaction, is the method that has the loop, is it also annotated with `@Transaction`? Otherwise you will not have a single transaction FYI

Comment: I have updated the question:the failure is that some children get lost. I have a junit test which calls a  method on a service bean that saves in a loop using `CrudRepository.save(List<Parent> parents)` and is annotated with @Transactional.

Comment: When you change parent, do you update both `child.setParent()` and `parent.setChild()` ? Your issue is very broad, can you try to test cases & try to find a small example that has the issue? Like when parent A and parent B swaps child, parent B has no child, something like that?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by "I update both sides of the relationship". I will try to extract a clean test case. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not strictly be what you are looking for, but an option might be not to reuse the child entities but assign copies of them instead.

On each source parent you would remove the child you want to move and then add a copy of it to the target entity.

You should then be able to call `CrudRepository#saveAll()` on the list of parent entities that were changed this way and get the expected result.

The caveat is that the ids on the moved children would be changed in the database as they would be deleted and then reinserted. The solution is not optimal regarding performance as you would be doing a bit more work both on the DB and Java level.

Comment: That solves the task, but can lead to quite some database traffic because children and their children need to be deleted and re-inserted. I'll accept the answer if no one has a better solution.

Comment: another caveat: hibernate inserts the children as duplicates before it deletes the original children, i.e. the children cannot have domain attributes that need to be unique in the corresponding table.